# Laravel Migration Failure

Tags: php, mysql, database, batch-file, laravel-5

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by `batch` asc, `migration` asc' at line 1 (SQL: select `migration` from `migrations` orders by `batch` asc, `migration` asc)
```

I am using Laravel 5.1 and I have previously deleted all of my tables within Sequel pro. I am using MySQL. The problem is that I keep receiving this error each time I run PHP artisan migrate for a fresh new installation. I have removed references to my various service providers and I have also commented out my entire routes file without success. Within the migrations table there is just one migration.

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(false);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
```

This is the migration I cant seem to get going and I have tried composer dump-autoload, php artisan migrate install I am having problems trying to figure out how to troubleshoot this any further. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not correct on order by:

```
orders by -> order by
```

Comment: OK I have removed the orderscontroller and the orders table from the migration and the order model and each time I try to migrate I receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You sql have error **orders by**:

```
select `migration` from `migrations` orders by `batch` asc, `migration` asc
```